# Call jquery function on "onSelectedIndexChanged"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two drop-downs and one text box.
I want to display multiplication of selected values from both the drop-downs.

So i am trying to call a jquery function on "OnSelectedIndexChanged" even of dropdowns. Hoever I am getting error during build in Visual studio.

my code is :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProbability" runat="server" Width="125px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="javascript:calculateRiskFactor();">
```

Errors are: `Invalid expression term ':' and
Invalid expression term ')' and some more`

Is anything wrong with syntax or this is wrong way to call a function?

The whole page code is something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Submit_Risks.aspx.cs" Inherits="Risks_Submit_Risks" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/SAPMaster.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">    
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Validation.js"> </script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="contain">
        <div class="title">
            Risks</div>
        <div class="data">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMsg"></asp:Label>
            <table class="style1" align="center">

                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        Probability (P)
                    </td>
                    <td class="style3">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProbability" runat="server" Width="125px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvProbability" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlProbability"
                            InitialValue="0" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ErrorMessage="Probability" ForeColor="Red"
                            Text="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        Impact (S)
                    </td>
                    <td class="style3">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlImpact" runat="server" Width="125px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvImpact" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlImpact"
                            InitialValue="0" ValidationGroup="vgSubmit" ErrorMessage="Impact" ForeColor="Red"
                            Text="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/656/Using-JavaScript-to-handle-drop-down-list-selectio)

Comment: try it like this OnSelectedIndexChanged="calculateRiskFactor();"

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can remember from ASP.NET WebForms, `OnSelectedIndexChanged` only points back **to a .NET server-side function**, which ASP.NET calls with a postback (correct me if I'm wrong).

To bind client-side code to the control (like with jQuery), why not use jQuery to do it for you?

```
$('select[id$="ddlProbability"]').change(calculateRiskFactor);
```

Comment: I am trying this...however this event is never triggered..I also tried debugging.. :(

Comment: Ok sorry...Now the event is triggered but at the time of page loading and not after changing value of dropdown...

Comment: hell yeah, you should try debugging. hahaha. :D in any case, are you sure that you're using the right jQuery selector to bind the handlers to?

Comment: Yes...I have used $('select[id$="ddlProbability"]') and it is correct as I did alert for its html and i got expected result..

Comment: I'm suspicious that your dropdown triggers a postback when you change its value, since it's a .NET-generated dropdown. If that's the case, then your page is refreshing, and whatever `calculateRiskFactor` does is completely invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProbability" runat="server" Width="125px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="calculateRiskFactor()">
```

Comment: As function is in different js file I am again getting error.

Comment: Do you add the link in this files? show me full page if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register Client Side `'onchange'` event of DroDownlist..you can register the `onchange` event using

```
DropDownList1.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnSelectedIndexChange();")
```

`OnSelectedIndexChange()` is a javascript function that will be call when on client Side when DropDownListBox seleted index is changes.